# deleting a file with string in the arguments

Tags: c++, string, visual-c++

How can i remove a file from the directory in `c++` ?

I know this function `int remove ( const char * filename )` deletes the file whose file name is specified in the argument. But it accepts only `char*` . Is there any other function in c++ that accepts `string` as it's argument ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have a `std::string`, you can get a `const char*` from it by calling its `c_str()` member function.

The `remove` function from `<cstdio>` is part of the C Standard Library.  C has no concept of classes or `std::string`, hence why the function takes a `const char*` and not a `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can use the Boost libraries, you might want to look into Boost::Filesystem instead. It's a replacement for the file handling routines in <cstdio>.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by James, you can call [remove()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/remove/) with your `string` C-equivalent, which can be obtained by calling [string::c_str()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/).
(Haven't tested this code, but that's the idea):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    string filename("filename.ext");

    if (remove(filename.c_str()) != 0)
    {
        perror("Error deleting file");
    }
    else
    {
        puts("File successfully deleted");
    }

    return 0;
}
```